# angular - generate sitemap.xml from @angular/router

Tags: angular, router, sitemap

I have an angular application with a small routing file like following

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/common/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/contact/contact.module').then( m => m.ContactPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Is there a mean to generate file sitemap.xml containing both url contact and home when building the application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import your `routes` into `sitemap.ts` making sure to add a data object to each route with `loc`, `lastmod`, `changefreq` and `priority`.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: LandingComponent,
    data: {
      loc: "/",
      lastmod: "2022-04-07",
      changefreq: "daily",
      priority: "1.0",
```

and then

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as path from "path";

const HOSTNAME = "your-url-goes-here"
const sitemap = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">`
  .concat(
    routes
      .map((route) =>
        createUrl(
          `${HOSTNAME}${route.data.loc}`,
          route.data.lastmod,
          route.data.changefreq,
          route.data.priority
        )
      )
      .join("\n")
  )
  )
  .concat("\n</urlset>");

fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./src/sitemap.xml"), sitemap);
```

Then you can add `sitemap.ts` to your package.json

```
...
"build-sitemap": "ts-node -O '{\"module\": \"commonjs\"}' ./sitemap.ts"
}
```

Comment: I've been using it in production for some time now, works well

Comment: I don't get it to work. I have imports from my Angular files. `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ...\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2015\core.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of ...\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2015\core.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.`

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool that *claims* to do what you ask:
https://github.com/Comcast/sitemapper-for-js

Follow the instructions in [this article](https://medium.com/@iamssurya/generating-xml-sitemaps-for-angular-react-73514c2a62a6) to set it up.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for this post let me check if this reply to my need